# Мониторинг информации с веб-интерфейса в Zabbix

Tags: json, веб-программирование, администрирование, zabbix, мониторинг

Всем добрый день! Прошу вашей помощи, т.к. никак не могу решить задачу с Zabbix. У меня есть сервер Zabbix и веб-интерфейс OISenMon 1.0.1, который мониторит температуру с USB датчика (скрин веб-интерфейса во вложении). Проблема в том, что я никак не могу настроить в заббиксе веб-сценарий, который будет мониторить конкретную строчку, выдавая её значение. Кто умеет в это дело, прошу вашей помощи!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiqb6.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWHDc.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o64jB.png

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)